# How to get m3u8 file from video website

Tags: video, m3u8

There are some tools like you-get, youtube-dl tools which can parse video actual urls. Now I want to get m3u8 file, how can I do it? Surfing the Internet, I know those tools often get actual urls from m3u8 files.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "http://example.com/chunklist.m3u8" -codec copy file.mp4`

Answer (score -3):

You can use wget to download m3u8 file create folder on your desktop, and create example.bat file from pc copy cmd.exe put it in same folder with example.bat and open it copy code below paste in to it and save double click example.bat will download .m3u8 file for a example

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://live.netd.com.tr/S2/HLS_LIVE/cnn_turk/index.m3u8
```